# SSIS Package Corrupted - How to resurrect?

Tags: ssis

A SQL Server SSIS project is corrupted when I pull it up in Visual Studio.  However, the job behind this project/package is still running correctly and it is creating the proper extract file.  Is there a way to pull the SSIS package down from the server as opposed to pulling it from a local project file?  We tried restoring from an earlier backup version but that was also corrupted somehow.  The timestamp on the file doesn't show it as having been modified for years so we're not sure what went wrong at this point we're just trying to resurrect the project/package.  Any help you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: I've generally been able to open .dtsx files just copied from the production server in SQLServer BI Design Studio, if thats what you are asking.

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  in mgmt. studio I connected to server/integration services, expanded the packages, right clicked on the package, chose Export.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case only project file gets corrpted, leaving all other dependent files(packages, project params, connections etc) as they are. So i generally create a new project file and add all the existing files to it and its good to go.